# How can I scan a One-Wire (1-Wire) bus for all connected devices and list their IDs

Tags: fpga, 1-wire, serial-bus

I have written a One-Wire (1-Wire, OW) controller in VHDL for FPGA designs. Currently I use a USB-OW adapter from Dallas/Maxim on my PC to get the sensors' IDs. I would like to scan the bus directly from the FPGA and collect all IDs on that bus.

How can I do this? It should be possible, because the shipped software from the USB adapter can list all devices on the bus.

Enumerating all devices is to slow, because OW has very long IDs. I used this technique on I²C, because there are only 127 addresses to scan :).

Comment: Did you read the one-wire documentation? There is a bit-wise elimination procedure that let you discover all devices on the bus without enumerating all addresses.

Comment: I implemented the 1-Wire controller regarding the [DS18S20](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18S20.pdf) temperature sensor's documentation. It can perform: reset pulses, send and receive bits, send receive bytes, calculate CRCs, ... I have not found any documentation on enumerating the bus. I have also not found a common 1-Wire documentation :( Is there a document that regards 1-Wire, but is not device specific?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maxim has an application note titled [1-Wire Search Algorithm](https://www.analog.com/en/app-notes/1wire-search-algorithm.html):

The strategy is too involved to accurately describe here, but the basic principle is based on:

- 1-Wire is an open drain bus: multiple devices can pull the bus to *GND* simultaneously.
- `0`s are encoded as long low pulses, `1`s as short low pulses (by actually not pulling the bus low).  If multiple devices write the same bit to the bus, that bit appears on the bus.  If any device writes a `0` to the bus, a `0` appears.
- as reply to the 1-Wire *Search ROM* command, all (selected) devices will, bit by bit, first write their own ID bit \$A_i\$, followed by the inverted ID bit \$\bar{A_i}\$.  Then the master writes a bit \$S_i\$, which will select the devices for the next bits.

Based on these properties, the master can detect whether

- no selected devices are present: both \$A_i = 1\$ and \$\bar{A_i} = 1\$.
- devices with a 0 as ID bit are present: \$A_i = 0\$
- devices with a 1 as ID bit are present: \$\bar{A_i} = 0\$

This way you can see which bits are still available in your search space, and you progress down that binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

This [DS1820 datasheet](http://www.systronix.com/Resource/ds1820.pdf) explains the "ROM search" on P 10.

Comment: Hmmm, the ROM search example was removed in the newer revision (rev 2, 1/15) of the DS18S20 documentation. Thanks for the link to the old one.