# More than 1-Wire interface (SWI) (ex DS24132) discovery and identifications

Tags: 1-wire

Just started experimenting with 1-wire (SWI) communications. I am currently waiting for my DS2413 and iButtons to arrive. I have been searching for information and there are lots of examples. My question is more practical than how.

Most of the SWI libraries have a search function. So discovering them seems easy. Here is a discussion in this forum. [How can I scan a One-Wire (1-Wire) bus for all connected devices and list their IDs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/176452/how-can-i-scan-a-one-wire-1-wire-bus-for-all-connected-devices-and-list-their?rq=1)

My qustion is a little different. After discovering the serial number (64-bit ID), how does the software, know this serial number (64-bit ID) goes to this physical chip? For example, say I have more than one DS2413, one is driving "sensor 1", two is driving "sensor 2", three is driving "sensor 3" and so one. The search enumerated 3 64-bit ids. How does the software know which 64-bit ids go to which sensor?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: **it doesn't**.

You have to connect those sensors one by one the first time and take notes about their IDs. There are some Onewire chips which allow you to select a few bits of their ID or daisy-chain them for topological enumeration but these are exotic. For most Onewire chips, you have to take notes.

Comment: Thanks, that was my assumption but I wanted to make sure. I was thinking manufactures would not want to customize code for every board manufactured, so I was thinking there was a chance for a solution.

Comment: If you use up to four DS2413 on a board, you could identify them by a different pullup/pulldown pattern on the PIOs in the default state.

Comment: If I am hearing correctly, it would use 3 IO pin on the microcontroller, 1 for the data bus and 2 to identify which DS2413. Give up 3 pins for 4. Now if you give up 4 IO on the microcontroller, 1 for the bus and 3 address for 8 IO pins. I guess you might as well go with I2C IO expander at some point.

Right now this is just academic thinking for me as far as DS2413.  The iButtons are what I have some ideas on.

Comment: No. You could simply arrange your outer circuit and **overload** the pin function so you could detect if there's a circuit with pullup or pulldown connected to a pin when reading from it and being sure that's the default state. There are two PIOs on each DS2413 so you can identify up to four of them this way. But nowadays homebrew Onewire chips are the way to go. I use Onewire I/Os only if I had dozens of metres between identical individual boards. You cannot do that with I²C.